# Android Google Services: API key and SHA-1 fingerprint for release and debug

Tags: android, release, android-debug, google-play-services

I was able to build a release-apk successfully in android studios.

My app uses some services from Google like Google App Invites and Google Places for Android.

To get these services, I had to register a API key on the google developers console which looks like this:

[image]

I'm unsure about the package name and SHA-1 fingerprint section of getting an API key.

If I have both a debug and a release version of my app (let's say the package name is com.myapp), do I put in the com.myapp as the package name twice but set the release and debug SHA-1 respectively for each package name?

So:

```
com.myapp (SHA-1 fingerprint) S1:2D:3F etc
com.myapp (SHA-1 fingerprint) D2:1W:2V etc
```

I tried to do that but so far the release version of the app does not seem to want to work at all.

APP_INVITE says:

> No Android client ID is found for package name com.myapp.
>   (APPINVITE_CLIENT_ID_ERROR)

PLACES AUTOCOMPLETE says:

> Error getting autocomplete prediction API call:
>   Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_INVALID_APP, resolution=null}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - after some investigations, yes, you do put your package name twice and then you put the SHA-1 fingerprint for the release and debug version separately. This will make PLACES work.

Also, from my investigations, I noticed that the APP_INVITE error pointed to no client ID found for the package. Please note that this is referring to your OAuth 2.0 client IDs which can be found under your API keys in your Google Developer Console. Changing that SHA-1 key (there is no option to put in a development SHA-1 and a debud SHA-1in this case) will result in APP_INVITE working.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit confusing, I think the best solution to get rid of such scenarios is to add an `applicationIdSuffix` so you (and any other service) could distinguish between builds: `com.myapp.beta` for build and `com.myapp` for release.

I'd recommend you to take a look at this detailed tutorial: http://medyo.github.io/2015/different-android-app-resources-gradle-build-type/

Hope that answers your question

Comment: I'm afraid you are a little too late. I have solved my problem. See my answer below.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, it'll work however you won't be able to distinguish which key corresponds to which build?I highly recommend using id suffixes.

Comment: Good point. I have unfortunately left signing the app for release to the last minute so I will have to use my quick fix method for now instead and will use your solution going forward. Thanks again +1

Comment: With pleasure, please mark the answer as accepted, so other guys in the same situation could easily find the solution.